# Set cookie in after() hook nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I tried to set cookie in nightwatch after() hook function but apparently it didn't work. The idea is I want to set the cookie's value as "failed" if the test failed and "success" if the test passed.

```
export = {
  '@tags': [ 'heboh' ],

  after(browser) {
    browser
      .setCookie({ name: 'mycookie', value: 'success' })
      .getCookie('mycookie', function callback(result) {
        console.log(result); // print null
      })
      .end();
  },

  'create heboh'(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.title('Facebook'); // intended to make it failed
  }
}
```

I specified --verbose and this is what I got

```
FAILED:  1 assertions failed and 1 passed (5.446s)
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session/null/cookie
 - data:  {"cookie":{"name":"mycookie","value":"true"}}
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":45}
INFO Response 404 POST /wd/hub/session/null/cookie (19ms) { sessionId: 'null',
  value:
   { error: 'invalid session id',
     message: 'No active session with ID null',
     stacktrace: '' },
  status: 6 }
LOG     → Completed command cookie (22 ms)
INFO Request: GET /wd/hub/session/null/cookie
 - data:
 - headers:  {"Accept":"application/json"}
INFO Response 404 GET /wd/hub/session/null/cookie (15ms) { sessionId: 'null',
  value:
   { error: 'invalid session id',
     message: 'No active session with ID null',
     stacktrace: '' },
  status: 6 }
null
LOG     → Completed command cookie (16 ms)
LOG     → Completed command end (0 ms)
```

Looks like there is no session in after() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I believe you need to call done on your after hook.

```
  after: function (browser, done) {
    browser
      .setCookie({name: 'mycookie', value: 'success'})
      .getCookie('mycookie', function callback(result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .end()
      .perform(function () {
        done();
      });
  }
```

Comment: right, I forgot to call done(). Thank you @schroedes for the clue.